Unable to copy docker image to ZOT registry using Skopeo
I have installed Zot registry version v2.0.1 by following this document. The registry is installed successfully and I see it running. Now I want to copy an image from my local directory to the Zot registry using Skopeo. For this I installed Skopeo version 1.15.0.
Now I am trying below command to copy the docker image from my local directory to Zot registry
skopeo copy --debug --insecure-policy --dest-tls-verify=false docker-archive://home/nginx/nginx-docker.tar docker://127.0.0.1:8080/nginx:latest

But I am getting following error
DEBU[0000] Checking if we can reuse blob sha256:f703cc7a0e636538ae9767121d6da7501de03437277ef5549459ab886978806d: general substitution = true, compression for MIME type "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip" = true
DEBU[0000] Checking if we can reuse blob sha256:458ecd8dac6739be741006504b1fe187dda55ab9eb124e7cd79d5f1c9bb74975: general substitution = true, compression for MIME type "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip" = true
DEBU[0000] Checking if we can reuse blob sha256:b6663d435f614d8f69f8550221eeb6bd5a71428a7414795304172b9c8fcf50e9: general substitution = true, compression for MIME type "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip" = true
DEBU[0000] Checking if we can reuse blob sha256:c1a9cf18a19777a0a930f5fc83fc7fab1c4eb97ba601341cfc026375b203ff67: general substitution = true, compression for MIME type "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip" = true
DEBU[0000] Checking if we can reuse blob sha256:8d29e380f219d107d99970fa08b6b1b86ab0bb32ac88704a5d628a4a3bbf9726: general substitution = true, compression for MIME type "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip" = true
DEBU[0000] Checking if we can reuse blob sha256:e49d7f89f9f88204bd7d17276b761f3cd69885db7a6a2e77f108952c0d3b855a: general substitution = true, compression for MIME type "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip" = true
DEBU[0000] Checking /v2/library/nginx/blobs/sha256:c1a9cf18a19777a0a930f5fc83fc7fab1c4eb97ba601341cfc026375b203ff67
DEBU[0000] Checking /v2/library/nginx/blobs/sha256:8d29e380f219d107d99970fa08b6b1b86ab0bb32ac88704a5d628a4a3bbf9726
DEBU[0000] Checking /v2/library/nginx/blobs/sha256:f703cc7a0e636538ae9767121d6da7501de03437277ef5549459ab886978806d
DEBU[0000] Checking /v2/library/nginx/blobs/sha256:e49d7f89f9f88204bd7d17276b761f3cd69885db7a6a2e77f108952c0d3b855a
DEBU[0000] Checking /v2/library/nginx/blobs/sha256:b6663d435f614d8f69f8550221eeb6bd5a71428a7414795304172b9c8fcf50e9
DEBU[0000] Checking /v2/library/nginx/blobs/sha256:458ecd8dac6739be741006504b1fe187dda55ab9eb124e7cd79d5f1c9bb74975
DEBU[0000] GET https://127.0.0.1:8080/v2/
DEBU[0000] Ping https://127.0.0.1:8080/v2/ err Get "https://127.0.0.1:8080/v2/": http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client (&url.Error{Op:"Get", URL:"https://127.0.0.1:8080/v2/", Err:(*errors.errorString)(0x10580a540)})
DEBU[0000] GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/v2/
DEBU[0000] Ping http://127.0.0.1:8080/v2/ status 400
DEBU[0000] GET https://127.0.0.1:8080/v1/_ping
DEBU[0000] Ping https://127.0.0.1:8080/v1/_ping err Get "https://127.0.0.1:8080/v1/_ping": http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client (&url.Error{Op:"Get", URL:"https://127.0.0.1:8080/v1/_ping", Err:(*errors.errorString)(0x10580a540)})
DEBU[0000] GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/v1/_ping
DEBU[0000] Ping http://127.0.0.1:8080/v1/_ping status 400
FATA[0000] trying to reuse blob sha256:458ecd8dac6739be741006504b1fe187dda55ab9eb124e7cd79d5f1c9bb74975 at destination: pinging container registry 127.0.0.1:8080: StatusCode: 400, "{\"message\":\"no matching operation was found\"}\n"


I tried to look at the logs of Zot registry but could not find anything. For some reason the ping is not working well. Any help?

zot is a OCI-only registry, so
skopeo copy --format=oci ...

https://zotregistry.dev/latest/user-guides/user-guide-datapath/

I also tried adding the format=oci but the result is still the same.

Here is a list of steps.
$ skopeo --version
skopeo version 1.9.1-dev commit: dbe47d765a0a30274854ee8d8cbe9a2bc8c8352e

$ docker info | grep Version
 Version:    24.0.5
 Server Version: 24.0.5

$ docker pull alpine:edge
$ docker save alpine:edge -o /tmp/alpine.tar

$ skopeo copy --format=oci --dest-tls-verify=false docker-archive:/tmp/alpine.tar  docker://localhost:8080/alpine:edge

Getting image source signatures
Copying blob 8980900bae6f done
Copying config 7d3e1b9ac9 done
Writing manifest to image destination
Storing signatures

